# Code compiles and runs in Visual Studio even though it has the name of a class that isn't referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have an ASP.NET Core web application I'm testing, and it shouldn't be compiling or running, but it does both.   The problem *should be* that I'm using a class name -- `ActionResult` -- from an assembly that isn't referenced.  Notice how `ActionResult` is not blue like a resolved class name, and also notice how there is no compiler error underlined:

[image]

Furthermore the project compiles and runs just fine (although doesn't behave as expected, naturally, which is to respond with HTTP GET requests to that URL with the values seen above).  What is going on?

[image]

Here's all the code just for reference:

**Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "api/{Default}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**DefaultController.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication2.wwwroot
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/Default
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> Get()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's VS and .NET info:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017
>   Version 15.9.4
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.4+28307.222
>  
>   Microsoft .NET Core 2.1

Comment: Also, how do I get the %#$% GIF to stop playing on demand?!

Comment: It could be a problem with `.csproj.user` file. Try deleting it together with bin/obj folders close VS and open again.

Comment: Isn't it a `ActionResult` from `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`? See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Okay then why isn't it showing up as blue like other classes, and why can't I see it's definition by hitting F2?

Comment: It's a bug in VS. Not your code. If you close the document and reopen, the error should disappear.

Comment: @rory.ap Visual studio also uses caching for meta-data and saves it to temp files like `x.csproj.user`... Try deleting this file and re-add the `AspNetCore.Mvc` library...

Comment: Also can you provide info from dotnet --version and vs version

Comment: @itikhomi  -- edited.

Comment: @Fabjan  -- not using ReSharper

Comment: Deleting .user file didn't fix it.

Comment: For anyone who's interested: I "solved" the mystery (sort of).  The problem, apparently, was that the `DefaultController` class resided in the `wwwroot` folder in my project.  I moved it up one level and suddenly everything worked.

Comment: BTW, removing the `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;` also allowed it to compile just fine, so go figure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ActionResult` is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace which you are in fact referencing. Visual Studio just isn't highlighting correctly, which is a bug I encounter off and on.